# How to handle saved images locally vs on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

I want to save some generated images.

The part which im confused about is how to handle the paths for saving files.

When running locally (in VS) the images can be saved in **c:\images**, but on the server id probably want to save them in **root-of-webdir\images**

do i need a configurable path in the web.config? how can i read the url path for the images in both cases?

Comment: are you familiar with `Server.MapPath`

Comment: `Raklos` I would suggest reading up more about what `~` does within a web application as well as what `./` or `../../` does within a web applicaiton just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) to get the local directory name:

```
var folder = Server.MapPath("~/images");
```

This will usually give you 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\images'.

Comment: will  i need a configurable property for this path?

Comment: No. `~` refers to the application root folder so you are ready to go.

Comment: my project is held in c:\project\me\etc... in order to save to c:\images should it know  this path?

Comment: The code provided will only work with relative paths. So `~/../images` should work too. Otherwise, save it as [application setting](http://odetocode.com/articles/345.aspx) in the web.config.

Comment: @raklos Addendum to this answer: your application (e.g. AppPool Identity) must have the proper permissions to the path (e.g. `modify` to save). When you run/debug _locally_ your app runs in _your user context_ (elevated privileges), on server, that will not be the case. Hth..